# On Windows 7, is there a command prompt line that can start cmd as an administrator?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, administrator

On Linux, we can use

```
sudo bash
```

to run a shell as the superuser.

On Windows 7, we can use

> *Start* menu -> (in search box, type) cmd -> Right click on search result and choose Run as Administrator

to run a command prompt as an administrator. Is there also a command prompt line that is like Linux's `sudo` or `su` so as to start a shell as an administrator?

Comment: You can also search for cmd (like you already do) and press "ctrl+shift+enter" to launch the selected program as administrator.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [`runas` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) is the closest thing to what you're looking for:

```
runas /user:username cmd.exe
```

The format is `runas`, the username you want to run as, other options, and then the program you want to run.

If you're on a domain, you can use:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME cmd.exe
```

This can be run from the `Run` box ( <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> ) or from a command window.

Note, however, that this is not exactly like `sudo` - you can't use it to elevate yourself, just run something as a different user. If you're already have administrative rights, a runas to your account will give you the same access as the regular command (unless, of course, you runas a *different* administrator account, which will grant those administrator's rights to the new shell).

Comment: Also, unlike `sudo`, `runas` will never cache the password for any length of time. So if you were planning on queuing up a couple quick commands like you can with successive runs of `sudo`. So just open a console window and run your commands there.

Comment: so the shortest form is "runas /user:DOMAIN\Administrator cmd.exe" wow... that's pretty long and hard to remember... and i can create an alias, but what if i am on someone else's computer and helping out? will it be a good idea if MS can create a special command called runasadmin?

Comment: Joshua: Unless you use `/savecred`.

Comment: +1, and for local admin `runas /user:administrator cmd.exe` is not hard to remember after a dozen types or so. All it is is the command itself `runas` followed by the `/user:` switch, followed by the user we want to run it as, then finally the program we want to run, `cmd.exe` (the command prompt in our case). This is as close to a one line you can get for running command prompts elevated. Also, if you do start->run sometimes there's a checkbox to run the program elevated, I haven't put any effort into figuring out what makes it appear, but it is an option.

Comment: But what is the `administrator` password? It doesn't accept a blank one. If I right-click > Run as administrator, it doesn't ask me for a password (possibly because my user account has admin privileges, but this is different from run as admin, which will run with elevated rights).

Comment: It appears that by default the administrator does not have a password. And that the account is actually disabled. The administrator account needs to be first enabled, given a password and then it becomes an actual user that you can log into and runas into.

Answer (score 11):

Try creating a shortcut to cmd.exe. Right Click > Properties.
Click on Advanced button. And tick the box "Run as Administrator" and click OK.

Assign it a shortcut key if you want.

And you could also assign the default location for the CMD prompt to start in.. eg %CD%

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is to click <kbd>Start</kbd> and type **cmd**, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Source: [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Use [SuRun](http://kay-bruns.de/wp/software/surun/).

It works on Windows 8 as well. It runs the application in "admin" mode without a prompt, yet you have greater control on what applications are run (you can see it on the SuRun's control panel applet). It works great in a batch file too...

Comment: just a note for Windows 8 (and 8.1): I was not able to launch a command prompt as admin, because surun replaces - by default settings - the built-in runas function in the context menus.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a command-line solution: download hstart from http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html and extract hstart.exe or hstart64.exe to somewhere on your path. You can start an elevated command prompt with `hstart /runas cmd` or `hstart64 /runas cmd`.

But the fastest way (as noted in a comment for the question) is still to press Windows, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Create a batch file such as sudo.bat, and type the following commands and then save in the PATH:

```
@echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") > %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo args = Right("%*", (Len("%*") - Len("%1"))) >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo objShell.ShellExecute "%1", args, "", "runas" >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@cscript %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
```

To use it, for an instance, `sudo cmd net start fms`, however, the script won't work if there's quotemark in command line.

Comment: This results in prompting user with UAC dialog box, and then running the desired command in a separate window.

Answer (score 1):

I was frustrated with the existing solutions for this, so I wrote a little [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) script which should be more familiar to *nix users.

It elevates the current user with no password prompts (just [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control)), redirects stdin and stdout, and runs in the same console window.

https://github.com/tehsenaus/windosu

Comment: This works great - just say `sudo <command>` and hit Alt+Y in the UAC dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You might like [Sudo for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/).

Answer (score 0):

The [Open Command Prompt Shell Extension](http://code.kliu.org/cmdopen/) can add this capability for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I include genuine `su` and `sudo` commands with my [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/cshell.htm) to run a command as another user or elevated (with the UAC prompt) or both, i.e., elevated as another user.  Unlike `runas` and other alternatives, my `su` and `sudo` know how to pass current directories, environment variables and long command lines.  This is a commercial product but there is a [free version](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Demo.htm).  Full disclosure:  I'm the author.  But I'm also happy to answer questions.