# Windows 7 Administrator Command Prompt "Start in" Path

Tags: windows-7, command-line, runas

So, I know you can create a shortcut to an administrator-level command prompt (as described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/74564/on-win7-is-there-a-command-prompt-line-that-can-start-cmd-as-an-administrator)), but what I'm seeing is that whenever I use such a shortcut, it always drops me into c:\windows\system32\ path.

I've tried specifying that shortcut's properties to set the "start in" path I need, but to no avail. It seems any time I run **cmd.exe** "As Administrator," it completely disregards the shortcut's paths and sticks to c:\windows\system32\

Any suggestions on how to get Windows 7 to respect the shortcut's "start in" path?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I found a way around this. In the shortcut, change the command line to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "cd c:\"
```

In this case it changes the starting directory to the root of C:. You can set your own parameters.

Comment: But what is the reason?

Comment: You're still specifying a fixed directory instead of landing in the same directory from which the shortcut is activated.

Comment: If you want to run a program in the directory, append (without quotes) "& myprogramname.exe" at the end of the command line above.

Comment: "pushd c:\" would also work when setting up a administrative cmd shortcuts

Answer (score 10):

It will happen if the place where you want to open your command prompt is on a different drive than the shortcut is. The solution is to put an additional command in the shortcut:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "a: & cd a:\something"
```

In this case it will change to the drive a: from the current drive, and than open the a:\something folder. The & operator is used to put multiple commands in a single line at the windows command prompt.

Comment: `cd /d a:\something` will change to a different drive and directory

Comment: This would work too: `pushd a:\something`

Answer (score 3):

**Launch an elevated Command Prompt from the context menu**

To add the **Open Command Window Here (Administrator)** option to the context menu for file system folders, use the following REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Open Command Window Here (Administrator)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

To add the entry to Computer (My Computer) context menu, use the following REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\shell\runas]
@="Open Command Prompt (Administrator)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe"
```

**Usage**

Copy the above contents to Notepad, and save the file with .REG extension. Then right-click the REG file and choose **Merge**.

*[Source](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/113/1/How-to-open-an-elevated-Command-Prompt-from-the-folder-context-menu-in-Windows-Vista.html)*

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but not quite what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to create an arbitrary shortcut, which I can pin to the taskbar.

Comment: i'm not sure if this is possible, unless you change the start directory for CMD globally: To change default path where cmd starts add/edit REG_SZ Autorun in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor replacing the Value Data with a folder or directory preceded by a CD\

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do:

First I create a shortcut for cmd.exe and place it into a directory that I will always keep from computer to computer.. e.g. c:\PersonalData\Windows Customize\Admin
then I edit the shortcut to read as below (Domain and AdminUser you will need to change)

C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:domain\AdminUser /savecred "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k cd c:\PersonalData"

Then I create a toolbar on my taskbar that points to the "Admin" Folder.. this is where I keep all my admin tools ... this works on WinXP and Windows 7..

Another thing that I will do is change the color of my background of this cmd prompt that easily identifies that I have my admin credentials open...   if you want to be more secure take out the /savecred then it will prompt you for your admin password every time

Answer (score 2):

Easiest option I have found is to add a registry key.  Run the following from an elevated command prompt:

REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "CD /D C:\"

NOTE: Close the command prompt afterwards and reopen and it will change to the root of the C drive.

This will work for all users.

Alternatively adding to current user works too (put it in a logon script, startup folder etc) but this would be dynamic of course.

Comment: thank you, start in doesn't work...this solves it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Update on [@Molly7244's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/87398/windows-7-administrator-command-prompt-start-in-path/#87400).

1. Add nice icons
2. Only visible on *Shift* (as you are used to with standard cmd window)
3. Hotkey on *'a'*

[image]

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Add 'Open command window here (Administrator)' context menu
;Extended means it shows on shift key
;Hotkey on 'a'

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas]
@="Open command window here (&Administrator)"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\imageres.dll,-5324"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Open command window here (&Administrator)"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\imageres.dll,-5324"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""


;Add icon also to standard 'Open command window here'

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd]
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\imageres.dll,-5323"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd]
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\imageres.dll,-5323"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can right click CMD, select *Properties* and in the "*Start in*" box clear whatever is there, entering: `%SystemRoot%\system32`. Click OK.

Comment: This is not a good answer, the question explicitly said that the `start in` parameter isn't working, something which I can confirm in my Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was given by Peter, but if you want to switch to a drive other than c: (assuming Windows is on c:) is to use

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "cd /d d:\some_directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a *.bat file through a shortcut marked with "run as administrator" you can change to the folder of the *.bat file by adding in the beginning of the *.bat file the following row: cd %~dp0

Comment: maybe you need converted to a comment rather than an answer; just flag and ask.

Answer (score 0):

I use Powershell ISE instead - it has tabs!!

In windows 10 this worked for me

I changed the properties/start in in following location

drive:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools

Command prompt shortcut was here

If you use powershell they live under

AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell

I changed the Start-in field to D:\data\local and now all new instances launch there