# When I start command prompt w/ administrative rights, the "Start in" location is igored. Any way to avoid this?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Administrator Command Prompt “Start in” Path](https://superuser.com/questions/87398/windows-7-administrator-command-prompt-start-in-path)

I have it set to c:\myfolder. If i click Start->Command Prompt it opens a console window started at c:\myfolder.

If i use Ctrl+Shift+click (start a program w/ administrative rights) to start Command Prompt, it opens to c:\windows\system32.

Why? And how to fix this?

Comment: Giscard - Refer to answer provided by `Molly` - http://superuser.com/questions/87398/windows-7-administrator-command-prompt-start-in-path

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/87398/windows-7-administrator-command-prompt-start-in-path

Answer (score 0):

only if you change the default startup directory for the command prompt globabally, so it will always start in this directory:

- Click Start, Run and type Regedit.exe
- Navigate to the following branch:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Command Processor

- In the right-pane, double-click Autorun and set the startup folder path as its data, preceded by `"CD /d "`. If Autorun value is missing, you need to create one, of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` or `REG_SZ` in the above location.

alternatively you may add this option to your contect menu:

**Launch an elevated Command Prompt from the context menu**

To add the **Open Command Window Here (Administrator)** option to the context menu for file system folders, use the following REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Open Command Window Here (Administrator)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

To add the entry to Computer (My Computer) context menu, use the following REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\shell\runas]
@="Open Command Prompt (Administrator)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe"
```

**Usage**

Copy the above contents to Notepad, and save the file with .REG extension. Then right-click the REG file and choose **Merge**.

*[Source](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/113/1/How-to-open-an-elevated-Command-Prompt-from-the-folder-context-menu-in-Windows-Vista.html)*