# How can I update the default directory for Windows Command Processor to be my home directory?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, default-settings

When I run `cmd.exe`, the directory I start in is my home directory (`C:\Users\Edd>`)

When I pin cmd.exe to the start menu and run it from there the directory I start in is `C:\Windows\System32>`

How can I update the default directory for Windows Command Processor to be my home directory?

A quick note: aside from the difference in default directory, the titles of the windows are also different. cmd.exe has the title "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" and when I run it from the pinned menu item it is "Windows Command Processor".

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/87398/windows-7-administrator-command-prompt-start-in-path/155863#155863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a shortcut that starts cmd.exe, right-click on it, choose Properties, and change 'Start in' to the desired directory.

Comment: You can use environment variables, so %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% vs a hard coded path.