# Change cmd home directory

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

My doubt is how I can change the directory that opens by default when opening cmd.

For example:

```
c: \ Users \ User
```

and I want it to open in:

```
c: \ Users \ User \ Desktop
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42596129/3536342

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1312668/windows-7-opening-command-prompt-with-shortcut-icon-in-directory-of-icon/1312681#1312681

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/916016/how-to-change-cmd-start-directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change CMD start directory](https://superuser.com/questions/916016/how-to-change-cmd-start-directory)

Answer (score 3):

You need to

> Right-Click on "Command Prompt" icon, select "Properties", and edit
>   the "Start In" property to your desired path.

Or, you can just do

```
Windows + R
```

and paste this:

```
cmd /K "cd C:\YOURFOLDER\"
```

Comment: In this case, it would be: **`cmd /K cd/d "%userprofile%\Desktop" `**