# How to start administrator cmd.exe in desired location other than default system32 path

Tags: windows-10

Because of Windows 10 security restrictions, I cannot run a software (WirelessModem.exe of D-Link) I used to run easily on Windows 8.1. However, I can run it from a CMD command prompt run under Administrator account. To make it convenient to open the software whenever I need it, I created a shortcut on my desktop, set it to run as administrator, set the target to "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" and *Start in" to the location where my said software is located, as shown in the following screenshots. Nevertheless when I run this shortcut, UAC prompts for Administrator confirmation and when I hit OK, CMD opens with system32 path, rather than the location I specified earlier in shortcut properties, why?
[image]
[image]

Please note that creating direct shortcut to wirelessmodem.exe does bring up a pop-up in red notice reading "This app has been blocked for your protection" so the only hack I know is to run wirelessmodem.exe from an admin CMD window. So, my main concern in this question is to start cmd in the location of the said app, not in Windows' system32.

Comment: It seems that the "Start in" directory is ignored when `cmd` is run as administrator, but there is a good work-round [here](http://superuser.com/questions/87398/windows-7-administrator-command-prompt-start-in-path).

Answer (score 2):

1. The *Start In:* location is where CMD.exe would open, *not* a file it would execute.
2. Why not just use a shortcut to D-Link Connection Manager, set to *Run as Administrator*? Create the shortcut, right-click on it to select *Properties*, and use *Advanced* properties settings to set *Run as Administrator*, as below:
   [image: Advanced Properties dlg]