# Windows 8.1: Windows command prompt (Cmd) shortcut "Start in" not taken into account when run as administrator

Tags: windows, command-line, administrator, file-shortcut

I have a shortcut to a Cmd prompt configured like this:

```
Target: %comspec% /k "SET "TMP=F:\workspace" & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""
Start in: -Some path here-
```

This works fine. The command prompt opens in the specified path.
But when i open the link with "Run as administrator" or i configure the shortcut with Advanced/Run as administrator, the command prompt will always open in C:\Windows\system32 instead of the specified Start-in-path.
Why is this and how can i fix it so that the command prompt will open in a specified path?

Comment: You Really need that file to run with administrator privilege

Comment: @TechieGossip. No, but i need that the remaining prompt is one with admin privileges.

Comment: I think this link will help u. https://superuser.com/questions/87398/windows-7-administrator-command-prompt-start-in-path

Comment: Yes, i found this too and it helps, thanks. Still searching for an explanation why "Start in" is disregarded when run as admin.