# Force CMD.EXE to run as admin

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On Windows 7, is there a command prompt line that can start cmd as an administrator?](https://superuser.com/questions/74564/on-win7-is-there-a-command-prompt-line-that-can-start-cmd-as-an-administrator)

Is it possible to force `cmd.exe` to always run with administrator rights?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/74564/on-win7-is-there-a-command-prompt-line-that-can-start-cmd-as-an-administrator

Comment: Related but certainly not a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in Windows Vista or Windows 7:

- Press start
- Type "cmd"
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Press Yes to accept the resulting [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) prompt (or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on Windows Vista, or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> on Windows 7)

This method will run any application as administrator.

Comment: Pressing <shift>+<ctrl>+<enter> gives a message box "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe: Unspecified error"... what could this mean? Windows 7 home premium.

Answer (score 9):

In Windows Vista/7 follow these steps to always run the command prompt as an administrator:

1. Click Start. Type **Command**. Right-click **Command Prompt**, and then click **Properties**.

   [image]
2. On the **Shortcut** tab, click **Advanced**.
3. Select the **Run as administrator** checkbox.

   [image]
4. Click **OK** twice.

Now, when you launch a Command Prompt from the Start Menu, UAC will prompt you for administrative privileges.

Comment: You can not do this for command prompt

Comment: but of course you can, screen shots added.

Comment: I have checked this box, but running the shortcut brings me to a `C:\Users\Username` prompt, which I think means it is **not**  running as administrator!

Comment: @SanjayManohar the Start path is also specified in the Shortcut properties. Most likely you just have C:\Users\--Username-- as the start path. I've confirmed this works for me. I think this is a better solution than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows XP, you could create a short cut to cmd.exe in the Quick Launch area and then right click -> Properties and change the Target field. You would preface the command with `runas /noprofile /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME`

The full text of the command on my computer is

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\runas.exe /noprofile /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
```

Comment: You can also edit the "Advanced" settings on shortcut properties and check "Run as administrator".

Comment: I don't see this in XP but you can do that in 7.