# Can I nest a command string within another command string?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

Whenever I run the following command in an elevated command prompt, I get the 0x80070005 Access Denied error code. I'm assuming it's a permissions error for the child shell. I'm running the command in an elevated prompt on Winddows 7 Pro SP1.

> FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-* 9.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart"

**Can place the "Runas" command within the already nested command in order to run the child shell as an admin?** I don't think I can because of conflicts with quotation mark locations. If there's another way to do this, such as via a batch file, I'm open to alternative methods, although I do prefer running it as a single string.

Sidenote1: Ignore the space after the first asterisk in the command string. It was added one for aesthetics & accuracy.

Sub-question: Could I use this "fix" to circumnavigate the problem entirely?
[Prompt as Administrator?](https://superuser.com/questions/453409/how-can-i-always-run-the-command-prompt-as-administrator)

[Reference for Runas #1](https://superuser.com/questions/74564/on-windows-7-is-there-a-command-prompt-line-that-can-start-cmd-as-an-administra)

[Reference for Runas #2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx)

Comment: ForFiles is awkward. It always launches a subshell without elevation. Just use the FOR command instead with () to bundle the echo and pkgmgr calls in one statement after the for.