# How to run cmd with Admin privileges using command line

Tags: windows-8, command-line, cmd.exe

Is there a way to run/start **cmd** as **administrator** through the **command line** or a **batch file** programming in Windows 8?

I want to create a batch file which has administrative privileges without any prompt to the user.

Comment: Have a look at the SU question: [On Windows 7, is there a command prompt line that can start cmd as an administrator?](http://superuser.com/questions/74564/on-windows-7-is-there-a-command-prompt-line-that-can-start-cmd-as-an-administra). As far as I remember you cannot bypas any UAC popup without disabling UAC completely

Comment: Related: *[On Windows 7, is there a command prompt line that can start cmd as an administrator?](http://superuser.com/questions/74564)*

Answer (score 5):

```
runas /profile /user:administrator “Driver:\folder\program”
```

For example, the administrator account is “AAA” and you want to run BBB.exe of C:\programs, you should follow these steps:

1. Press Win key & R
2. Input “CMD” in open box and click “OK”
3. Input: runas /profile /user:AAA “C:\programs\BBB.exe”  and press “Enter”
4. Input the password of administrator AAA
5. Press “Enter”

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `runas.exe /savecred /user:administrator cmd`or refer this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/05cce5f6-3c3a-4bb8-8b72-8c1ce4b5eff1/how-to-run-a-program-as-adminitrator-via-the-command-line?forum=w7itproappcompat)

Answer (score 0):

```
REM  --> Check for permissions  
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"  

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.  
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (  
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...  
    goto UACPrompt  
) else ( goto gotAdmin )  

:UACPrompt  
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"  
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B  

:gotAdmin  
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )   
    pushd "%CD%"  
    CD /D "%~dp0"
```

Comment: You should put some additional content in this answer explaining what it is doing rather than just proving some back code mixed with VBS and no explanation leaving people that don't know this code scratching their head wondering what it does. I'd look it up and test with it regardless if it was me using it and not understanding it but you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can download already created portable and clean (generated in the `Windows XP`) shortcut files set: https://sourceforge.net/p/contools/contools/HEAD/tree/trunk/Scripts/Tools/ToolAdaptors/lnk/

Or even generate your own: https://sourceforge.net/p/contools/contools/HEAD/tree/trunk/Scripts/Tools/ToolAdaptors/vbs/

*Usage example*:

```
cmd_admin.lnk /C ...
```

Each lnk file just a link to the `cmd.exe`, so you can pass here all the `cmd.exe` command line options.

**Pros**:

- You don't need a localized version of Administrator account name like for the `runas` method.

**Cons**:

- You start elevated only the `cmd.exe` process. To start any other process you have to either run it from the `cmd.exe` script, or create another standalone shortcut with the `Run as Administrator` flag raised.
- Run from shortcut file (`.lnk`) in the Windows XP (but not in the Windows 7) brings truncated command line down to ~260 characters.
- Run from shortcut file (`.lnk`) loads console windows parameters (font, windows size, buffer size, etc) from the shortcut at first and from the registry (HKCU\Console) at second. If try to change and save parameters, then it will be saved ONLY into the shortcut, which brings the shortcut file overwrite.

Comment: If you promote your own software on this site, you *must* disclose that it is yours.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I don't promote or advertise anything. And this is open source, why I have to disclose an open source that it is mine?

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/promotion

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' A Windows shortcut is a binary file. I can't post here a binary file snippet. How you suppose to do that?