# Get administrative right in windows command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, administrator

I am not trying to do cheeky things, but my need is just to have two scripts for adding or removing IP routes using the following command in batch scripts:

Add route:

```
@echo off
route add -p 20.20.188.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.122.254
exit
```

delete route:

```
@echo off
route delete 20.20.188.0
exit
```

My question is that now I cannot get it run just by double-click on the batch file. I always have to right click and choose: `Run as Administrator` option even my user is in the Administrator group.

Is there any way to introduce a command like `sudo` in Linux or anything else that can make me happy by just double-clicking on the file.

UPDATE:

I tried the `runas` solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/74565/68986) but as the answer state:

> Note, however, that this is not exactly like sudo - you can't use it
>   to elevate yourself, just run something as a different user. If you're
>   already have administrative rights, a runas to your account will give
>   you the same access as the regular command (unless, of course, you
>   runas a different administrator account, which will grant those
>   administrator's rights to the new shell).

It is not a solution for my problem.

Comment: Basically you want to force those batch files to run with administrator rights, isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [On Windows 7, is there a command prompt line that can start cmd as an administrator?](http://superuser.com/questions/74564/on-windows-7-is-there-a-command-prompt-line-that-can-start-cmd-as-an-administra),  [Is there any 'sudo' command for Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows)

Comment: Yes exaclty; I saw some post with runas option but it does not look to be helpful.

Comment: An answer for this can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Double-click

Comment: @ruffp There is more than one answer on those questions, and I'm not sure why you wouldn't find the posts regarding RunAs 'helpful', but hey, there they are. :)

Comment: The duplicate link does not answer my question:  If you're already have administrative rights, a runas to your account will give you the same access as the regular command (unless, of course, you runas a different administrator account, which will grant those administrator's rights to the new shell).

Comment: @techie007 I already tried these answer and none are working for me. the link provided by JonCarl is interesting as well but it does not work for me.

Comment: _None_ of those answers work for you in any way?  What "doesn't work" about them?

Comment: @techie007 in fact the solution pointed by JonCarl seems to work but it is just a bit slower. anyway I think the solution provided by laika is the best one as no third party or (slow) system call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shortcut to such batch script and then

- in context menu  click *Properties*
- under *Shortcut* click *Advanced* button
- select *Run as administrator*

Comment: Ah it is funny to see the "run as administrator" is grayed out on the batch file but another option exist on the shortcut (and the same option is still greyed out on the shortcut). Thanlks anyway it is the simplest way I will use.

Answer (score 1):

As you [mentioned in your comments](https://superuser.com/questions/719007/get-administrative-right-in-windows-command-line#comment920627_719007) using `runas` as the same user will not elevate you. There is no method I know of built in to windows that will elevate an already running command prompt.

In the past I have used 3rd party tools like [`Elevate.exe`](http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/) which will do the job for you, you just use it like you would use `runas`, just add the `elevate` program to your `PATH` variable and you can just do

```
elevate route add -p 20.20.188.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.122.254
```

Comment: Interesting to see alternative, but I'd prefer laika's answer as there's no third party software to install.

Answer (score 0):

I use "eldo" and "eldoGUI" for this purpose (running batch files elevated). They are available [here](http://www.4neurons.com/other/Vista/tips.html), although I have absolutely no idea who created them in the first place.

Call eldoGUI like this:

```
Z:\eldoGUI.exe Z:\Backup-Music.cmd
```

This will produce the usual UAC prompt and proceed to run the command.